# Create a dataframe based on character vectors pairs connected by (,) and separated by a space

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following data.frame:

```
b<-structure(list(b = c("47.83006,11.71699 47.83004,11.71691 47.83002,11.7168 47.83001,11.71662", 
"47.83001,11.71662 47.82993,11.71628 47.82991,11.7162 47.82988,11.71614 47.82983,11.71609 47.8295,11.71588 47.82919,11.71566 47.82898,11.71549 47.82845,11.71504 47.82832,11.715 47.82821,11.715 47.82712,11.71531 47.82639,11.71549 47.82606,11.71561 47.8257,11.71567 47.82548,11.71574 47.82433,11.71613", 
"47.82433,11.71613 47.82436,11.7165 47.8244,11.71715 47.82442,11.71742 47.82453,11.71823 47.82459,11.71856 47.82492,11.7199", 
"47.82492,11.7199 47.82495,11.72005 47.82503,11.72034 47.82515,11.72066 47.82526,11.72093 47.82556,11.72172 47.82559,11.72182 47.82561,11.72191 47.82562,11.72201", 
"47.85051,12.11965 47.85092,12.11997", "48.10034,11.75948 48.10021,11.75938"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

It consists of coordinates lat,lon pairs separated by a space.

How could I create a data.frame or data.table as efficient as possible from this structure that would put lat and lon values in separate rows?

```
Lat       lon
47.83006  11.71699
47.83004  11.71691
47.83002  11.7168
…
```

**UPDATE**
Thank you for the solutions.
I Will go with @Gki proposal because its faster:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                         expr
 c <- b %>% separate_rows(b, sep = " ") %>% separate(b, into = c("Lat",      "Lon"), sep = ",", convert = T) %>% data.frame()
                                     d <- read.csv(text = unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), col.names = c("Lat",      "Lon"))
       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 12.363628 13.031700 14.027860 13.408883 13.703157 28.922909   100
  1.020622  1.050315  1.119533  1.117269  1.170826  1.348833   100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split by the space between the values and then use `read.csv` to get the `data.frame`.

```
read.csv(text=unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), col.names = c("Lat", "Lon"))
#        Lat      Lon
#1  47.83004 11.71691
#2  47.83002 11.71680
#3  47.83001 11.71662
#4  47.83001 11.71662
#5  47.82993 11.71628
#6  47.82991 11.71620
#7  47.82988 11.71614
#...
```

Or using *Forward Pipe Operator* `|>` and *function* shortcut `\()` in *base* since *R 4.1.0*:

```
strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE) |> unlist() |> (\(d) read.csv(text=d, col.names = c("Lat", "Lon")))()
#        Lat      Lon
#1  47.83004 11.71691
#2  47.83002 11.71680
#3  47.83001 11.71662
#...
```

Or using *bizarro pipe* `->.;` instead of defining a function:

```
strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE) |> unlist() ->.; read.csv(text=., col.names = c("Lat", "Lon"))
```

When skipping setting the column header, converting to numeric and having a matrix as result a fast way will be:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), ",", TRUE))
```

or converting it to numeric:

```
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), ",", TRUE))), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Using the `data.table` solution from @mt1022 for comparison:

```
library(data.table)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = do.call(rbind, strsplit(unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), ",", TRUE))
, baseNum = matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), ",", TRUE))), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
, data.table = as.data.table(tstrsplit(unlist(strsplit(b$b, ' ', T)), ',', T))
)
#Unit: microseconds
#       expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
#       base  28.829  30.2965  33.08313  31.5705  33.0475  85.880   100  a 
#    baseNum  29.832  31.3030  33.51445  32.3635  34.5395  56.851   100  a 
# data.table 143.745 147.9900 155.41194 150.9960 157.2420 278.190   100   b
```

Comment: Thank you! sadly i cant get Forward Pipe Operator approach to work since my R version is probably a bit older 4.05 but csv approach is very fast.

Comment: Nice solutions (never heard of base R pipe operator), but benching on microseconds is pretty much meaningless IMO

Comment: @DavidArenburg Pipe in base is new since Today (4.1.0). Yes benching is meaningless, jut showing it, as it was used for selecting a answer and another showing data.table is faster.

Answer (score 4):

If you can do it in `tidyr`

- separate the extra pair of values into new rows using `separate_rows` with `sep = ' '` argument
- separate lat and lon values into different columns using `separate` with `sep = ','` argument along with `convert = T` which will convert values into numeric simultaneously

```r
b<-structure(list(b = c("47.83006,11.71699 47.83004,11.71691 47.83002,11.7168 47.83001,11.71662", 
                        "47.83001,11.71662 47.82993,11.71628 47.82991,11.7162 47.82988,11.71614 47.82983,11.71609 47.8295,11.71588 47.82919,11.71566 47.82898,11.71549 47.82845,11.71504 47.82832,11.715 47.82821,11.715 47.82712,11.71531 47.82639,11.71549 47.82606,11.71561 47.8257,11.71567 47.82548,11.71574 47.82433,11.71613", 
                        "47.82433,11.71613 47.82436,11.7165 47.8244,11.71715 47.82442,11.71742 47.82453,11.71823 47.82459,11.71856 47.82492,11.7199", 
                        "47.82492,11.7199 47.82495,11.72005 47.82503,11.72034 47.82515,11.72066 47.82526,11.72093 47.82556,11.72172 47.82559,11.72182 47.82561,11.72191 47.82562,11.72201", 
                        "47.85051,12.11965 47.85092,12.11997", "48.10034,11.75948 48.10021,11.75938"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyr)

b %>% separate_rows(b, sep = ' ') %>%
  separate(b, into = c('Lat', 'Lon'), sep = ',', convert = T) %>%
  data.frame()

#>         Lat      Lon
#> 1  47.83006 11.71699
#> 2  47.83004 11.71691
#> 3  47.83002 11.71680
#> 4  47.83001 11.71662
#> 5  47.83001 11.71662
#> 6  47.82993 11.71628
#> 7  47.82991 11.71620
#> 8  47.82988 11.71614
#> 9  47.82983 11.71609
#> 10 47.82950 11.71588
#> 11 47.82919 11.71566
#> 12 47.82898 11.71549
#> 13 47.82845 11.71504
#> 14 47.82832 11.71500
#> 15 47.82821 11.71500
#> 16 47.82712 11.71531
#> 17 47.82639 11.71549
#> 18 47.82606 11.71561
#> 19 47.82570 11.71567
#> 20 47.82548 11.71574
#> 21 47.82433 11.71613
#> 22 47.82433 11.71613
#> 23 47.82436 11.71650
#> 24 47.82440 11.71715
#> 25 47.82442 11.71742
#> 26 47.82453 11.71823
#> 27 47.82459 11.71856
#> 28 47.82492 11.71990
#> 29 47.82492 11.71990
#> 30 47.82495 11.72005
#> 31 47.82503 11.72034
#> 32 47.82515 11.72066
#> 33 47.82526 11.72093
#> 34 47.82556 11.72172
#> 35 47.82559 11.72182
#> 36 47.82561 11.72191
#> 37 47.82562 11.72201
#> 38 47.85051 12.11965
#> 39 47.85092 12.11997
#> 40 48.10034 11.75948
#> 41 48.10021 11.75938
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you AnilGoyal. Also learned so much! Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

This solution is by far not as excellent as provided by GKI and AnilGoyal. But it works. Here is solution with combination of `separate` and `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
b %>%  
  separate(b, c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l","m", "n", "o", "p", "q"), sep=" ",  extra = "drop", fill = "right") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=everything()
  ) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  separate(value, c("lat", "long"), sep=",") %>% 
  select(-name)
```

Output:

```
   lat      long    
   <chr>    <chr>   
 1 47.83006 11.71699
 2 47.83004 11.71691
 3 47.83002 11.7168 
 4 47.83001 11.71662
 5 47.83001 11.71662
 6 47.82993 11.71628
 7 47.82991 11.7162 
 8 47.82988 11.71614
 9 47.82983 11.71609
10 47.8295  11.71588
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution that is slightly faster here:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(
    base = read.csv(text=unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), col.names = c("Lat", "Lon")),
    data.table = as.data.table(tstrsplit(unlist(strsplit(b$b, ' ', T)), ',', T))
)
 # Unit: microseconds
 #       expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 #       base 354.102 360.5485 377.0983 371.2665 380.6985 527.916   100
 # data.table 151.252 161.8555 177.9840 178.1130 184.3945 348.759   100
```

Credit to GKi for the base R solution.

Comment: Its not faster than another *base* solution: `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(b$b, " ", TRUE)), ",", TRUE))), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)`

Comment: Nice solution. I used data.table very often and has the false impression that it is efficient on every aspect :(